# Django: Translate messages.success with variable

Tags: django

I want to translate my view.py. Usually, I did it like this `_("Ticket has been successfully created.")`

Now I want to add some variable to it. Can you explain me, how to translate it in that case in my views.py?

```
messages.success(self.request, f"Status of {discount.code} ticket has been successfully updated.")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Django official documentation you can find [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-python-code) like this:

```
def my_view(request, m, d):
    output = _('Today is %(month)s %(day)s.') % {'month': m, 'day': d}
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

So in your case it can be:

```
message = _('Status of %(discount_code)s ticket has been successfully updated.') % {'discount_code': discount.code}
messages.success(self.request, message)
```